# React Native: How to show the result of the newly added data immediately without reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In React Native, React Native: How to show the result of the newly added data immediately without reloading the page? in my current status, I can add data successfully but I have to refresh the page to reflect in my browser the newest or updated data in my database. this is my code

```
 import Profile from "../../components/profile";
 import AddProfile from "../../components/AddProfile";
 const [profilemanager, setProfileManager] = useState([]);

 const { data, refetch, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery('userData', async()=> {
    const _token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
    setToken(_token);
    await getProfileList(_token);
  });

  const getProfileList= (_token) =>{
    fetch(config.API_URL + '/profileManager/500/1', {
      method: 'GET',
      //body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
      headers: {
        //Header Defination
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      setProfileManager(responseJson);

    });
  }
  const addUserdataHandler = (selectedUserId) => {
      fetch(config.API_URL + '/profileManager/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({intuserid: selectedUserId}),
        headers: {
          //Header Defination
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        if(responseJson.hasOwnProperty("errors")){
          console.log("errors",responseJson);
          setSavingError(JSON.stringify(responseJson.errors));
        }else{
          setProfileManager(prevDMSMANAGER => [
            ...prevPROFILEMANAGER,
            { usersid:selectedUserId}
          ]);
  
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
  
  };


<AddProfile
      onAddProfile={addUserdataHandler}
      />
          <Text>{savingError}</Text>
        <View style={{zIndex:-1}}>
        <FlatList
            style={{minHeight:200,maxHeight:300, width:550}}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) =>index.toString()}
            data={profilemanager}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Profile
                key={item.usersid}
                id={item.usersid}
                Lastname={item.lastname}
                Firstname={item.firstname}
                Middlename={item.middlename}
                pressHandler={confirmDelete}
            />
            )}
        />
        </View>
```

this is from my  Profile.js

```
const Profile = props => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(props.title);
  const [isEditing, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const handleEdit = (dataToSend) => {
    props.pressHandler(dataToSend, props.id);
    console.log("props.id: ", props.id)
    setEdit(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.items}>
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Formik
          
          initialValues={{ 
            id:props.id,
            Firstname:props.Firstname,
            Lastname:props.Lastname,
            Middlename:props.Middlename

            }}
          onSubmit={handleEdit} 
          style={{flexWrap:'wrap'}}
        >
        {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit,isSubmitting, values, errors, isValid,touched,setFieldValue }) => (  
          <>
            <Text style={styles.itemText}>{props.Lastname} {props.Firstname}, {props.Middlename}</Text>
            <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                <Button title="Remove" onPress={handleSubmit} style={styles.editBtn} />
            </View>
            {(errors.UsersId && touched.UsersId) &&  <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column', flexBasis:'100%'}}></View>}

          </>
        )}
        </Formik>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

This is how I handled the add profile

```
  const addTodoHandler =async (dataToSend, { resetForm}) => {
    console.log("dataToSend: ", dataToSend.selectedUserId)
    await props.onAddProfile(dataToSend.selectedUserId);
    resetForm({})
  };


  return (
    <View >

    <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        validationSchema={ValidationSchema}
        initialValues={{ 
          selectedUserId:0
         }}
        onSubmit={addTodoHandler}
      >
    
        {({ handleChange, handleBlur,handleReset,resetForm, handleSubmit,isSubmitting, values, errors, isValid,touched,setFieldValue }) => (  
        <>
        <View style={forms.fieldRow}>
            {/* <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => dropDownRef.current.close()}> */}
              <View style={{padding:0,  width:250,flexDirection:'row',flexGrow:0}}>
                <DropDownPicker
                  name="selectedUserId"
                  value={selectedUserId}
                  defaultValue={selectedUserId}
                  zIndex={9000}
                  controller={instance => dropDownRef.current = instance}
                  searchable={true}
                  placeholder="Select a user"
                  searchablePlaceholder="Search a user.."
                  searchablePlaceholderTextColor="gray"
                  seachableStyle={{maxHeight:500, height:500}}
                  searchableError={() => <Text>Not Found</Text>}
                  onSearch={text => { searchUser(text)  }} 
                  items={users}
                  //defaultValue={country}
                  containerStyle={forms.dropdownStyle} 
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#fff', 
                    width:230,
                    paddingTop:10,
                    borderColor:'#dadae8', 
                    overflow:'hidden'}}
                  itemStyle={{
                      justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
                  }}
                  dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff', padding:10, width:200, height:400,  maxHeight:500,borderStyle:'solid', zIndex:999, borderColor:'#444',  shadowColor: '#000',
                  shadowOffset: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 1,
                  },
                  shadowOpacity: 0.22,
                  shadowRadius: 2.22,
                  elevation: 3,}}
                  onChangeItem={item => {
                    setFieldValue("selectedUserId",item.value)
                    setFieldValue("selectedUserName",item.label)
                    setSelectedUserId(item.value);
                  }}
                />
              </View>
             <View style={{padding:0,zIndex:-1,flexDirection:'row',flexGrow: 1}}>

              <Button title="Add" onPress={handleSubmit}   disabled={!isValid}/>
              </View>
        </View>
          <View style={{zIndex:-1}}>
          {(errors.selectedUserId && touched.selectedUserId) && <Text style={formStyles.errorText}>{errors.selectedUserId}
          </Text> }
          </View>
        
        </>
        )}
    </Formik>

</View>
);
};
```